# IdentityServer and Simple Injector integration in ASP.NET Core v1.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-4.5, identityserver4, simple-injector, asp.net-core-1.1

We use Simple Injector for our application components and we need to access a component inside of an IdentityServer interface implementation (`IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`), which itself is inside `IServiceCollection`. If I'm understanding it correctly we need to implement [ASP.NET Core MVC integration 4.0-4.5](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration_45.html) and use `container.CrossWire<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>(app)` (instead of `AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents()` since we target net452 in the ASP.NET Core 1.1 project). When I try to inject `ISignInManager` into `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` constructor after trying this implementation I get this error during verification:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator failed. The registered delegate for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator threw an exception. Unable to resolve service for type 'ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'.

Full exception:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator failed. The registered delegate for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator threw an exception. Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'. ---> SimpleInjector.ActivationException: The registered delegate for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator threw an exception. Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInstanceCreation(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify, Scope verificationScope)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
   at Authentication.Web.UI.IoCBootstrapper.InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in D:\IoCBootstrapper.cs:line 110
   at Authentication.Web.UI.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery, AppSettings appSettings) in D:\Startup.cs:line 132}
    [System.InvalidOperationException]: {System.InvalidOperationException: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator failed. The registered delegate for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator threw an exception. Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'. ---> SimpleInjector.ActivationException: The registered delegate for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator threw an exception. Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.Re
sourceOwnerPasswordValidator'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInstanceCreation(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify, Scope verificationScope)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
   at Authentication.Web.UI.IoCBootstrapper.InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in D:\IoCBootstrapper.cs:line 110
   at Authentication.Web.UI.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery, AppSettings appSettings) in D:\Startup.cs:line 132}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2146233079
    InnerException: {SimpleInjector.ActivationException: The registered delegate for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator threw an exception. Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet`1 callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg arg)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.BuildAndReplaceInstanceCreatorAndCreateFirstInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.GetInstance()
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()}
    Message: "The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator failed. The registered delegate for type IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator threw an exception. Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'."
    Source: "SimpleInjector"
    StackTrace: "   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyInstanceCreation()\r\n  
    at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInstanceCreation(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify, Scope verificationScope)\r\n  
    at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)\r\n  
    at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()\r\n  
    at Authentication.Web.UI.IoCBootstrapper.InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) in D:\\IoCBootstrapper.cs:line 110\r\n  
    at Authentication.Web.UI.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery, AppSettings appSettings) in D:\\Startup.cs:line 132"
    TargetSite: {System.Object VerifyInstanceCreation()}
```

How can I accomplish this? How can I inject a Simple Injector registration into ASP.NET DI registration?

Registrations:

```cs
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
    new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));
services.AddSingleton<IViewComponentActivator>(
    new SimpleInjectorViewComponentActivator(container));
services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);

container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

container.Register<ISignInManager, SignInManager>(Lifestyle.Transient);
..
//other registrations that used by SignInManager
..

container.CrossWire<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>(app);
```

We are using:

- Simple Injector 4.7.1
- SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore+MVC 4.0.12

Comment: Please post the full exception details. The exception seems to contain information that is both provided by Simple Injector and the ASP.NET Core configuration system. We need to see the full information of the exception and all its inner exceptions (message, type, stack trace).

Comment: But TBH, I would suggest upgrading to .NET Core 2 (or better 3) and upgrade the Simple Injector integration to  the latest packages. Many things have changed, improved, and fixed in recent integration packages.

Comment: @steven : Thank you for looking into this. I've added full exception detail in a pastebin. I also would prefer upgrading but it's not possible because of other components we simply have to target 4.5.2. Thank you again.

Comment: I updated your question to include the stack trace. A question should stand on its own, without having to load essential details from other sources.

Answer (score 2):

The exception states:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Authentication.Common.Interfaces.SignIn.ISignInManager' 
>       while attempting to activate 'Authentication.Web.UI.IdentityServer.ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator'.

This means that `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` depends on `ISignInManager` but no `ISignInManager` is registered in the ASP.NET Core configuration system.

Comment: Yes ISignInManager is registered in Simple Injector. I was under the impression of Crosswire would redirect ISignInManager resolution to Simple Injector, was I wrong? Is there a way to inject a Simple Injector registration into an ASP.NET DI component or do I have to register ISignInManager into ASP.NET DI as well?

Comment: Cross wiring is a one-way process. It allows Simple Injector to pull in dependencies from the .NET Core configuration system. If you need it the other way around, you will have to make that registration yourself in the `IServiceCollection`. For instance: `services.AddTransient<ISignInManager>(c => container.GetInstance<ISignInManager>())`